# JSON Schema Builder Program

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there an existing program that helps forming a JSON Schema?

Comment: What do you want JSON formatted to? Object -> JSON ?

Comment: I would just like to specify a protocol using JSON.

Answer (score 6):

There's this great tool to get you started on generating a JSON Schema: http://www.jsonschema.net/ . Just feed a sample JSON files and out comes out a JSON Schema that you can then tweak.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this demo one](http://exavolt.github.com/onde/#?schema_url=schemas/jquery-package.json). It is at an early stage but you can already edit jSON documents with a schema constraint as well as design a Schema itself.

And [here is an official thread about Schema-based JSON editor](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/json-schema/9vBdgkBGlV4):

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Orderly](http://orderly-json.org/). They have DSL for schema description and you can try it online.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one ([XML ValidatorBuddy](http://xml-buddy.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm)) which is actually an XML editor but it also supports JSON and especially JSON Schema editing. The editor is a Windows desktop application and can do auto-completion and syntax-coloring for JSON schema files. You can also validate your JSON files against JSON schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in [Liquid XML Studio](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/json-schema-editor), but its a commercial product

[image: Liquid Json Schema Editor]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly something that'll help you with a 'schema', per se, but it's a visual way to navigate and manage JSON data.

http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/